# AutoHotKey - How do I use the ControlClick function?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotKey.

I still don't understand how to use ControlClick, it just doesn't seem to click in the correct spot.

I have 5 World of Wacraft's open, and I want AutoHotKey to click directly in the center of these 5 programs when I press a key, however 4 of the games are on the second monitor (if that matters).

These are the coordinates:

```
Game 1 - Left (0) Top (0) Width (1920) Height (1080)
Game 2 - Left (1920) Top (0) Width (683) Height (384)
Game 3 - Left (2603) Top (0) Width (683) Height (384)
Game 4 - Left (1920) Top (384) Width (683) Height (384)
Game 5 - Left (2603) Top (384) Width (683) Height (384)
```

Game 1 is on a monitor with a max resolution of 1920x1080.
Game 2, 3, 4, and 5 is on monitor 2 with a max resolution of 1366x768.

This is the Window setup of all 5 games:

[image: window setup screenshot]

This is the script I had in mind (not the correct coordinates):

```
$F5::
ControlClick, x00 y00
Sleep, 100
ControlClick, x00 y00
Sleep, 100
ControlClick, x00 y00
Sleep, 100
ControlClick, x00 y00
Sleep, 100
ControlClick, x00 y00
return
```

I would really appreciate some help, I can imagine it's a really simple script for most of you.

P.S. In case you were wondering, I'm using ControlClick because the Click function moves your mouse, I don't want it do that.

Comment: Regarding "*I want AutoHotKey to click directly in the center of these 5 programs*": Does that mean you want to click into the center **of each** of these windows? If yes, what's the purpose of doing that? Please explain more in general what you're trying to achieve. Also, have a look at the [ControlClick docs](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm). This should get you started on how to use it; there's also a few examples.

Comment: I did actually mention I've already read the ControlClick docs, but it wouldn't let me specify the link I've read, and yes, I want it to click the center of each of the 5 windows, the reason for this, is because I'm multiboxing in World of Wacraft (playing multiple game clients simultaneously), and so I wanted it to use an ability which requires you to click on the ground, however I wanted it to do this on all 5 clients at the same time, instead of me doing it individually.

Comment: Also, I've tried using the ControlClick, but it doesn't seem to work when trying to click on the other 4 games (on the second monitor)... I.E. ControlClick, x960 y540 does not click directly in the center of Game 1.

Comment: I haven't seen you mention that you read the ControlClick docs. Anyway, one of the first sentences in the docs is: "*Specify the X and Y coordinates **relative to the target window**'s upper left corner*". Consequentially, if you don't specify a window, the Last Found Window will be used, which can be anything or nothing, but certainly not what you want. Since I haven't seen you mention that you've already read [the WinTitle docs](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm), I recommend you do so, and use it to target your windows.